# git apply change on unmerged paths

Tags: git, branch, rename

On branch A:

> > fileA.txt

On branch B:

> > someother/path/fileA.txt

I'm trying to cherry pick a change from branch A to branch B and I get :

> > deleted by us: fileA.txt

Is there any way to make git understand that the file was moved to a new path and I would like to apply the changes on `someother/path/fileA.txt` without doing it manually

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question properly , Branch A doesn't know the path someother/path.
Only branch B knows this path.

Create a similar path on Branch `A`. move the file to the respective path and commit your changes on Branch `A`.

Now you can do a `cherry-pic` of this commit on Branch `B`

Comment: That can work. I was looking for a way to apply the patch, and then resolve the conflict by asking git to apply the change on a different file name. Is that impossible?